# [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__firebase_init__.a.firestore is not a function"

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I am getting this error when I try to run my page, which shows user information stored in my Firestore database.

The script for the page:

```
<script>
import db from '@/firebase/init'
import firebase from 'firebase'
export default {
 data(){
     return{
        users: []
     }
 },
 created(){
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser 
    db.firestore().collection('users').where('user_id', '==', user.uid).get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        let usersArray = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
             usersArray.push(doc.data());
        })
        this.users = usersArray;
      })
 }
}
</script>
```

The firebase init file (excluding the personal information about my api key, database id etc.)

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
var firebaseConfig = {

  };
  const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebaseApp.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true })
  export default firebaseApp.firestore()
```

And here is the router setup. (I did remember to import firebase here as well)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Index from '@/components/Index'
import Userinfo from '@/components/Userinfo'
import firebase from 'firebase'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Index',
      component: Index,
    },
    {
      path: '/profile',
      name: 'Userinfo',
      component: Userinfo,
    }
  ]
})    

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
      if(to.matched.some(rec => rec.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        let user = firebase.auth().currentUser
        if(user){
          next()
        } else{
          next({ name: 'Login' })
        }
      } else{
        next()
      }
    })
    export default router
```

Comment: In file `@/firebase/init`, put `console.log(firebaseApp.firestore())`. Seems to me that some problem in this part.

Comment: I am getting no errors when I console.log that file. It says the error is located at **src/components/Userinfo.vue** (the page script that I show in my question)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I solved the problem.
The solution was to change

```
db.firestore().collection('users')
```

to:

```
db.collection('users')
```